# Using Django all-auth in a standalone app: paths that do not start with 'accounts/' are NOT FOUND 404

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using Django 3.2, and am creating a standalone user registration and management app, that uses django-allauth to handle all of the registration functionality.

My stand alone app directory structure is like this:

```
core
   /core
      settings.py
      urls.py
      # ...
   /django-myown-userprofile
      /userprofile
          models.py
          urls.py
          # ...
      myapp.tox
      setup.py
      setup.cfg
      # ...
```

#### core/core/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   # ...
   path(user, include('userprofile.urls')),
   path(admin, admin.site.urls)
]
```

#### core/django-myown-userprofile/userprofile/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('accounts', include('allauth.urls')),
   path('accounts/profile', ProfileView.as_view(), 'user-profile'),
   # ...
]
```

When I attempt to access any of the allauth endpoints (e.g.):

> http://localhost:8000/user/accounts/login

I get the error 404 Not found. It seems that django-allauth is expecting the path to be of the form:

> http://localhost:8000/accounts/...

How do I change this behaviour of django-allauth ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a trailing slash `/` in your `accounts` path in `userprofile/urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
   path('accounts/profile', ProfileView.as_view(), 'user-profile'),
   # ...
]
```

With that it should work fine. Ensure also that the variables `user` and `admin` have string like values that refer to a route ending with a trailing slash. It's nice to be consistent with the trailing slash. You could add it to your `ProfileView` route to keep the consistency, but it won't matter much.

As an extra thing to keep in mind is that the routes and names you use for your custom views when defining `urlpatterns` shouldn't overlap the ones used by the `accounts` app in `django-allauth` (see https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py to check the routes and names used by `django-allauth` `account` views). Hope this helped!